# What is the difference between the fields associated with choice and to in the django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

What is the difference between the fields associated with choice and to in the django model?
eg what is the difference between frontal and number_of_rooms field
What is the difference between defining choice and creating a model and defining the domain of another model?
thanks in advance

#django models.py

```
            class Advertise(models.Model):
                owner = models.ForeignKey(to="advertise.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
                title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
                description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
                price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
                square_meter = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
                number_of_rooms = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=NumberOfRoomsChoices.CHOICES)
                building_age = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=NumberOfBuildingAgeChoices.CHOICES)
                floor = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=NumberOfFloorChoices.FLOOR_CHOICES)
                number_of_floors = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=NumberOfFloorChoices.FLOORS_CHOICES)
                number_of_bathrooms = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=NumberOfBathroomsChoices.CHOICES)
                heating = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=HeatingChoices.CHOICES)
                balcony_exists = models.BooleanField(default=False)
                using_status = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=UsingStatusChoices.CHOICES)
                fee = models.PositiveIntegerField()
                created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
                updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
                status = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=AdvertiseStatusChocies.CHOICES)
                visibility = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=AdvertiseVisibilityChoices.CHOICES)
            
                # collections
                frontal = models.ManyToManyField(to="advertise.Frontal")
                interior_feature = models.ManyToManyField(to="advertise.InteriorFeature")
                exterior_feature = models.ManyToManyField(to="advertise.ExteriorFeature")
                locality = models.ManyToManyField(to="advertise.Locality")
                transportation = models.ManyToManyField(to="advertise.Transportation")
                landscape = models.ManyToManyField(to="advertise.Landscape")
                sutiable_for_disabled =models.ManyToManyField(to="advertise.SuitableForDisabled")
            
                def __str__(self):
                    return f"{self.title}"
```

Comment: `choices` simply presents the choices through an iterable of 2-tuple. So you can not *dynamically* add an extra `number_of_rooms` option, whereas a `ForeignKey` refers to another model. In such model you can add/update/remove objects. The integrity of the `choices` is furthermore not guaranteed by the database.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand. 
Well, can't we do this directly by defining a field in the model? why do we define a different model and use it? what is the advantage?

Comment: that it constructs a table. Often these alse refer to *entities* that are not just one field, but it thus refers to a `User`, `Project`, etc.

Comment: very thank you for your help